# In group theory, is there some relationship between a group being simple and it being compact?

Tags: group-theory

As I understand it;

- If a group is simple it has no non-trivial invariant subalgebra.
- If a group is compact it's generators are hermitian.

Is there some relationship between these properties? Does one imply (or forbid) the other?

I'm sure this is covered some how in the wikipedia pages, but I'm not having much luck comprehending them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing groups, Lie groups and Lie algebras. What you are interested in are (connected) Lie groups. A connected Lie group is called *simple* (as a Lie group!) if its Lie algebra is simple, i.e. is noncommutative and contains no proper ideals. A Lie group is called *compact* if it is compact as a topological space. These two properties are somewhat related, namely, if ${\mathfrak g}$ is a Lie algebra with trivial center then any connected Lie group with this Lie algebra is compact if and only if the Killing form of ${\mathfrak g}$ is definite. Other than that, compactness and simplicity (for Lie groups) are unrelated.

Comment: Yes, your quite right, I am confusing those things. By the killing form being definite, do you mean positive definite or negative definite? As in http://mathonline.wikidot.com/definite-semi-definite-and-indefinite-matrices

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson Negative definite.

Comment: Happened to discuss this with my lecturer, they are confident that groups are positive when the killing form is *positive* definite (but I didn't have the nerve to ask them to cite that). How confident are you that negative definite => compact?

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson Your lecturer might be using a nonstandard convention for the Killing form which has the opposite sign of the usual one. Just Google "compact Lie algebra".

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson: You can actually work it out by yourself. The (standard) Killing form on a (real) Lie algebra is $<a,b>=tr(ad(a)\circ ad(b))$. For each $a$ in your (compact) Lie algebra, $ad(a)$ acts as a skew-symmetric matrix. Now, take your favorite (nonzero) skew-symmetric matrix $A$ and compute  $tr(A^2)$. Did you get a negative number? Then you just verified that the Killing form is negative definite.

Comment: quite possibly a non standard killing form, they are a physics professor.

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson: I guesses so; still does not hurt to ask your physics professor what is his/her convention for the Killing form. Maybe he/she is making a simple mistake.